# Why is my regex not grabbing the last character of the prefix?

Tags: regex

Using the following regex, the last character is always included in the result. I am not sure why. From everything I know, it should be ignoring the entire string including the S.

Regex: `(?!XQS|QS)\w+` or `(?!X?QS)\w+`

Test Data:

```
XQSedbc6ba985837c6fc990642cd3987769
QS3e05a46c5e0728bc72b40a5d5402d933
XQS10fc2d802c082c75bd069ebfad0f31a4
QS983b36e91e2ba2089760a4d41089a0b3
ea9b8c6ca9edd686f3a25c319d3f5507
```

The following strings are matched:

```
Sedbc6ba985837c6fc990642cd3987769
S3e05a46c5e0728bc72b40a5d5402d933
S10fc2d802c082c75bd069ebfad0f31a4
S983b36e91e2ba2089760a4d41089a0b3
ea9b8c6ca9edd686f3a25c319d3f5507
```

However I want the following strings:

```
edbc6ba985837c6fc990642cd3987769
3e05a46c5e0728bc72b40a5d5402d933
10fc2d802c082c75bd069ebfad0f31a4
983b36e91e2ba2089760a4d41089a0b3
ea9b8c6ca9edd686f3a25c319d3f5507
```

This needs to be matched as the entire regex at group 0. It works off an agnostic parser built in Java. I am trying to avoid code changes.

Comment: Try just [`(?:X?QS)?(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/aZcnwS/3), the value is in Group 1.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, sorry I should have included it in the question. I need it to match as an entire regex or "Group 0".

Comment: It's a look-ahead and tries to find a match. Since matching is from left to right the position right before `S` is the position where next following characters are not `X?QS`

Comment: But why do you need to get all in Group 0? What is the tool/language?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is a parser fed into another program that was built in Java. I can make code changes, where I would just build an excluder, but I would prefer to do this with the Regex to avoid those changes.

Comment: Try `(?:(?<=^XQS)|(?<=^QS)|^(?!X?QS))\w+`

Comment: What about `[a-f0-9]+`

Comment: If it's Java try `(?<=X?QS).+$|^(?:(?!X?QS).)+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your tool uses Java flavor you are in chance to use:

```
(?<=X?QS).+$|^(?:(?!X?QS).)+$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/SmHh90/1)

Breakdown:

- `(?<=X?QS)` Assert preceding characters are XQS or QS (You don't need `X?` either?)
- `.+$` Match up to end of input string / line
- `|` Or
- `^` Match beginning of input string / line
- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

  - `(?!X?QS).` Take one character if next characters are not X?QS
- `)+` End of CG, repeat as many as possible
- `$` End of input string / line

Answer (score 0):

Lookahead won't work for this case, as it just increments the position
until the assertion passes.

A look behind is what you need as it has more power.

`(?m)(?:\w(?<!^XQS)(?<!^QS))+$`

https://regex101.com/r/xbTHvF/1

But, you could go for the fastest way, and that is to just consume
what's in the assertion, and capture what's after it.

`^(?:X?QS)?(\w+)$`

Comment: I modified your first regex to `(?!X?QS).(?<!QS)\w+` since I thought you could reduce the steps engine takes for your first suggested regex - which looks for beginning of line. You may want to take a look.

Comment: @revo -  Yeah, that guards all positions. I had to put myself in each spot to test it. Hindsight though... You should change you're answer. Apparently it's the fastest way.

Comment: @revo - Making your regex PCRE style, the bench of the two equivalent ways:  `Regex1:   (?!X?QS).(?<!QS).+$
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   5
Elapsed Time:    0.60 s,   600.56 ms,   600556 µs
Matches per sec:   416,280


Regex2:   (?:(?<=XQS)|(?<=QS)).+$|^(?:(?!X?QS).)+$
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   5
Elapsed Time:    1.04 s,   1039.63 ms,   1039625 µs
Matches per sec:   240,471`

Comment: Still the _king_ though is => `Regex3:   ^(?:X?QS)?(.+)$
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   5
Elapsed Time:    0.52 s,   519.91 ms,   519909 µs
Matches per sec:   480,853`

Comment: I came to this solution as a result of looking at your own solution and I encourage you to have it in your answer. Besides, I was thinking about anywhere in string where first `X?QS` occurs not only beginning of line so it's more relevant to yours.

Comment: And thank you for providing a benchmark. That's something.

Comment: @revo - It's a fairly overlooked, but powerful technique. The consumer is the dot here. `(?!QS)` protects the dot from starting with `Q`, the `(?<!QS)` protects the dot from ending with `S`. Thus, it's more like boundary protection, allowing the position to roll forward insuring the dot will always start matching after QS if it's there. The `X?` is just fluff.

Comment: @revo - I was just running some tests. Seems the idea can be extended to more than 2 characters by expanding the lookahead. Like this one has 3 hard chars `(?!P?XYZ|(?<=X)YZ).(?<!XYZ)`. Any amount of _optional_ chars can precede it and they are protected too. This has a nice rolling affect on a string and will always skip the block in question.